# ActiveRecord::Relation code displaying instead of intended data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, associations, nested-attributes

I'm trying to display a list of reviews on my home page and at the same time show the ratings for each review.

I want a comma separated list of the different ratings attached to each review (based on the associated review_id); ratings are integers of -5 to 5. All I get when I load the page is this:

```
Review 1. #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9879749a50>
Review 2. #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9879749a50>
Review 3. #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9879749a50>
Review 4. #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9879749a50>
Review 5. #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9879749a50>
```

When I want to see this:

```
Review 1. 1, 5, 2, -3
Review 2. 2, -1
Review 3. 1, 1, 4, 5
Review 4. -5, -2, -3
Review 5. 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :ratings_attributes, :reviews_attributes

  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ratings, :through => :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews, allow_destroy: true
end
```

review model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :priority, :ratings_attributes
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ratings
end
```

rating model:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rating_count, :review_id, :timestamp, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
end
```

home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @reviews = current_user.reviews.order("position")
    @ratings = Rating.where(params[:review_id])
    @ratings_list = Rating.find(:all)
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing reviews</h1>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<br />
  <div class="span12">

<ul id="reviews" data-update-url="<%= sort_reviews_url %>">
    <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
        <%= content_tag_for :li, review do %>
            <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
            <%= link_to h(review.content), review %>

            <!-- this is where i want a comma separated list of the different ratings attached to each review; ratings are integers of -5 to 5. -->
            <%= @ratings %>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<br />
  </div>
<!-- for debugging that i'm actually getting through to the ratings data -->
<%= @ratings_list %>
<br />

<%= link_to 'New Review', new_review_path %>
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong in the controller or here in the html.

All that displays next to each review is something like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f987a9d7618>
```

Thanks in advance...and if you care at all, i'm working outside and a bug just flew up my nose.

Comment: where is the variable `@reviews` on index.html.erb coming from?

Comment: copy/paste error creating this question. in the home controller in my app, it is listed as @reviews - thanks for the pointer - not the issue in the app as i wouldn't even see the reviews

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably rendering the actual review objects rather than a string representation of them. Something like this should work in the view:

```
<%= @ratings.map { |rating| rating.rating_count }.join(", ") %>
```

That turns your collection of ratings into a collection of rating_counts and then joins them with commas.

I can't help with the bug up the nose though :)

Comment: Although looking at your model structure, I think you don't actually intend to render `@ratings`, but rather the collection of ratings for each review? If so, you can change `@ratings` in my code to `review.ratings`.

Comment: amazing. thank you...worked perfectly. i'll mark this as the answer, but would you also mind pointing me to a book or good resource where i could have learned about the map function myself? i'm ready to move from beginner, to intermediate and most of the tutorials drop off at beginner. i imagine it would be more of a ruby resource.

Comment: [Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) is a really fun beginner and intermediate book. I don't remember if the map method is covered, but it's the type of book that gets you in the right mindset to go look for such a method.

Comment: And glancing through the available methods in the [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) will help you keep in mind all the handy little things Ruby can do.

Comment: many thanks...ordering the book now and adding the enumerable module stuff to my kindle.

Comment: you can make this even cleaner if you do `<%= @ratings.map(&:rating_count).join(', ') %>`.

Answer (score 1):

Queries are lazily executed in rails. So when you do things like `Object.where(...)` it returns the relation object (like you're seeing). It will only get executed when you actually use it (i.e. loop or call `.all` (although I believe the `.all` changes slightly in rails 4)). To get a comma separated list you just need to do `<%= @ratings.map(&:rating_count).join(', ') %>`.